# Skybox is in Perspective View

Tags: directx, directx-9

My Skybox is in perspective view, the closer i go it comes near. I have disabled the D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE also.

```
Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD,GetTransform());

Device->SetRenderState( D3DRS_LIGHTING,FALSE);
Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE,FALSE);
Device->SetSamplerState( 0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP );
Device->SetSamplerState( 0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP );

Device->SetFVF(SKYBOX_VERTEX::FVF);

Device->SetStreamSource(0,m_pVertexBuffer,0,sizeof(SKYBOX_VERTEX));
Device->SetIndices(m_pIndexBuffer);

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    Device->SetTexture(0,m_skyTextures[i].TextureFile);
    Device->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST,0,0,4,i*6,2);
    //Device->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN,i*4,2);
}

Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE,TRUE);
Device->SetRenderState( D3DRS_LIGHTING,TRUE);
Device->SetSamplerState( 0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP );
Device->SetSamplerState( 0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP );
```

I want it to look far always.

Comment: Have you centered the skybox around the camera?

Comment: Oh! U mean do i have to change the position of the SkyBox according to the Camera position ?

Comment: Yes. This can be done by setting the translation part of the view matrix (the fourth row) to 0, 0, 0, 1. Or by applying an appropriate world matrix.

Comment: Yeah I know it, But is it normal that the skybox is in perspective view ?

Comment: What do you mean by perspective view? Usually, the skybox is always centered around the camera.

Comment: I think he means a perspective projection matrix. And yes thats right.